# Como fazer o ícone do bootstrap3 ficar transparente com bordas brancas?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

O ícone está assim no momento ->
[image]

E eu quero que ele fique assim ->>>
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<nav>
   <a id="contato_link" [routerLink]="['/admin']">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true">    </span>
    <br />
    Contato
</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/upload']">Fotos</a>
<a href="#">Endereço</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `glyphicon` é uma fonte, então ele recebe propriedades te texto como color, font-size, etc... Logo ele tb aceita a propriedade `text-stroke`, com ela vc consegue colocar um contorne no texto, no caso no ícone que na verdade é um caractere de uma fonte chama `glyphicon`.

Então como o `text-stroke` vc coloca o contorno, e como o `color: transparent;` vc coloca a cor da fonte transparente, ficando apenas o contorno da imagem do ícone.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00f 0%, #f00 100%);
}

#contato_link .glyphicon {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<nav>
    <a id="contato_link" [routerLink]="['/admin']">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
        <br />
        Contato
    </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/upload']">Fotos</a>
    <a href="#">Endereço</a>
</nav>
```

**OBS:** Suporte dos navegadores vc pode conferir aqui, não funciona apenas no IE. https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke e apesar de ter que ter o prefixo -webkit- funciona em vários navegadores.

Comment: Não não, o que eu quero é fazer ele ficar transparente por dentro e com as bordas brancas, tem nada ver com circulo em volta não, a imagem foi só ilustrativa

Comment: @user8465 acho que agora entendi, da uma olhada na edição que fiz na resposta,

Comment: cara entenda, não tem nada ver com circulos nem quadrados nem nada, o que eu quero é só que o ícone fique da cor transparente com as bordas brancas, como mostrado na segunda imagem, Meu Deu do céu, será que é dificil entender isso, é bom Ler as perguntas com atenção antes de responder, pelo amor de Deus

Comment: @hugocsl: Fazendo uma analogia com  svg acho que ele quer algo com `{stroke: withe; fill: none}`

Comment: @user8465 meu Deus é tão difícil vc expressar o que realmente precisa? Sua pergunta não é clara, se vc não sabe o que é uma imagem com preenchimento e sem preenchimento, ou não consegue dizer que quer a imagem sem fundo e só com o contorno me desculpe. Eu respondi com o que eu entendi

Comment: @AugustoVasques vc entendeu de cara que ele queria só o stroke do ícone? Ou só depois que ele explicou n comentário ai acima?

Comment: O faltou foi na pergunta o exemplo ser dado como o mesmo ícone. Ter mudado de telefone para a carteirinha tornou difícil a compreensão do problema devido as peculiaridades de cada imagem.

Comment: @AugustoVasques achei que só eu tinha entendo errado.... De qq forma, dei uma atualizada na resposta mostrando como fazer, se te interessa a técnica está descrita, Valeu a força :). []´s